# PHP raw text encoding

Tags: php, get, decode, encode

I am trying to encode some text from a PHP script that will be sent via GET to another PHP script. The data I am trying to send contains:

- `\x0A` (basically the same as \n)
- `\xoD` (basically the same as \r)
- `@`

I have tried every from of encoding method I can come up with (`rawurlencode`, `urlencode`, `base64_encode`...) and no matter what I do the receiving PHP script is never able to retain the formatting text listed above. If anyone can help me figure this out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Why do you use a `HTTP GET` request, why not the `POST` variant which is much better suited for such task?

Comment: Can you make a code example? Sending and receiving scripts? That way we can see where the problem is.